# Inject user's selected timezone to query

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have set my server s timezone to be UTC. My users can select their own timezones like UTC+2 etc. I have created a query to indicate when a shift is open or closed:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(NOW()), start_day
FROM Shifts
WHERE (start_day = LOWER(DAYNAME(NOW()))
       AND start_time < CURTIME()
       AND end_time > CURTIME())
   OR (start_day = LOWER(DAYNAME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
       AND start_time < ADDTIME('24:00:00', CURTIME())
       AND end_time > ADDTIME('24:00:00', CURTIME()))
```

I want to alter this query, NOW() and CURTIME() to match the settings of each user. How should I alter my query, to inject custom UTC in it? Is there another way to accomplish what I need ?

Comment: Why not convert time zones inside your application, *before* calling mySQL?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? NOW() - $timestampDif ? And what about CURTIME()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function will solve your problem.

- Syntax

  CONVERT_TZ(dt, from_tz, to_tz).

  **"from_tz"** is your server timezone (in your case , UTC).

  **"to_tz"** value can be given as a string indicating an offset from **"from_tz"**, such as '+10:00' or '-6:00'.
- Examples:

  ```
   SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','UTC','+2:00');
   SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', '-5:30');
   SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '-2:00', '+5:00')
  ```